What are pipewire factories
I'm currently looking into pipewire and how everything works and was reading this documentation. There are these objects that require a factory to be created.
What are these factories? Is there a list somewhere with available factories? It says they are

usually created by loading modules in context.modules

however, no where is documented how they are created or which modules I have to load? Which modules load which factories?
If somebody has some valuable resources feel free to share them!

From my basic experience, it seems like a "factory" is a protocol for what type of audio port / access point / node to create. Not sure what the types are, though. Coppwr has a list of factories to choose from, it's about 15 long.
